# Strange behaviour of mt_rand used for random plotting

Tags: php, random, plot, gd

That's the code which generates the x-marks:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $maxdata; $i++)
{
  $xcoord = mt_rand(50, 450);
  $ycoord = mt_rand(50, 450);
  imagechar($im, 5, $xcoord, $ycoord, $string, $black);
  if (($xcoord < 50) || ($xcoord > 450) || ($ycoord < 50) || ($ycoord > 450))
  {
    $p_bad += 1;
  }
}
```

But this happens (got bad marks and at y-coord):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0etfc.jpg

Rly don't know where is the problem, image size is 500 x 500 pixels, x-coord is from 50 to 450 pixel, and y-coord is from 50 to 450 pixel too ...

Comment: Doesn't `imagechar` draw the string from the top-left of the characters' areas? If so, each `x`'s point is actually a few pixels above it.  (Notice that there's no `x`s centered around 450 either.)

Comment: So, how to compensate that? I don't know the actual pixel-size of chars (especially when they are capital) ...

Comment: You could draw crossing lines rather than drawing a character.  Then you could center the two lines on the point `$xcoord, $ycoord`.

Comment: Well, I used `imagesetpixel()` which seems to do the job, but how can I increase the size of dots?

Comment: You said that I could draw a crossed lines, but is it possible to do that with a function which calls two times `imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $color);`? 
So to draw two lines, must call function `drawMe($color) { imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $color); imageline($image, $x3, $y3, $x4, $y4, $color); }`, right?
 Well, how to return not a two lines but 9 pixels, that structures a more visible dot? 9 lines of code works for me, but got a warning that parameter 1 is null? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure exactly what you're asking with that comment.  It sounds like you're not passing your `$image` instance to the `drawMe` function you defined, hence it being `null` when you pass it to `imageline`.  However, if I'm not understanding correctly, you may wish to write a new question altogether, as it has deviated considerably.